# How to get a green to show up like the charging battery on the iPhone lock screen?

Tags: ios, uicolor

I am trying to get a color to show up on screen just like the charging battery (shown here):[image: Charging Battery]

After looking at the Apple Documentation on `UIColor` [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html), I have attempted using both `colorWithHue:saturation:brightness:aplha:` and `colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha:` to get a color to show up like that.

For example when I use `colorWithHue:.3 saturation:.84 brightness:1 alpha:.5` on a black background, it renders a color like this:

[image: myGreen with colorWithHue:saturation:brightness:alpha:]

or the `colorWithRed:0 green:1 blue:0 alpha:.5` on a black background shows up like this:

[image: myGreen with colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha:]

It doesn't have that translucent or glossy look to it.

Is there a better method to use? Or do I just not have the values right? (I have tried many combinations)

Comment: The battery has about 10 different colors that it uses to give it the glossy look, and you wont be able to di it with just a single, just the way your eyes work. What you have matched up for the colors appears to be very simlar to the stripe in the middle. Add more to give a 3D effect, and lighten them up to make it appear glossy.

Comment: No need to guess. Take a screen shot and pull the image into one of a thousand different applications that will allow you to see the exact color information of any pixel you choose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UIColor` represents only one colour with an opacity value (if you've stated one). In your case you might want to either use images, or override the `drawRect` method in a custom `UIView` class (Core Graphics). Take a look [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/93563/Introduction-to-iOS-Graphics-APIs-Part-1) for a brief introduction to the latter.

Comment: You are right, I had to use Core Graphics.  I had never used Core Graphics before, so I went through the tutorial on Ray Wenderlich's website. The tutorial you linked to is great too. Thanks for the help.  http://www.raywenderlich.com/2033/core-graphics-101-lines-rectangles-and-gradients